# I want to get the maximum value from my S_ID column which is declared as varchar type

Tags: mysql, sql

My S_ID values are

```
S_1
S_2
S_3,...., S_11.
```

I use `SELECT MAX(S_ID) FROM stock_detail` to get the maximum value.

It is working till S_9 but when it reaches S_11: that query only give me S_9 as the maximum value. How can I do to get S_11 as the maximum value ? Please help me, I am just a beginner in programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the maximum value by using this construct:

```
select s_id
from stock_detail
order by length(s_id) desc, s_id desc
limit 1;
```

This puts the longer values first.

If you want to use `max()`, then you need to deconstruct the number.  Something like:

```
select concat('S_', max(replace(s_id, 'S_', '') + 0))
from stock_detail;
```

This allows you to get a *numeric* maximum value rather than a *character* maximum value, which is the root of your problem.